# SessionExpiryInterval MQTT5 has no effect?

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.0 and Camel 3.20.5 to receive messages via MQTT 5 and then send them to an S3 bucket. My Camel route is like this:

```
    from("paho-mqtt5://..
    ...
    &qos=1
    &cleanStart=false
    &sessionExpiryInterval=60
    &clientId=xx)
   .to(aws-s3)
```

An mqtt client publish 100 messages to a topic (e.g. `topics/topic1`). The aws-s3 client subscribes to that topic, but disconnects because a network issue. I use the ActiveMQ Artemis web console, and there I see the that those 100 messages are kept in the queue. If I reconnect the aws-s3 client 10-15 minutes later it consumes the messages even though the time specified in `sessionExpiryInterval` elapsed. Why have the messages not been deleted at the end of the 60 seconds?

From the [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/paho-mqtt5-component.html) I understood that they will be consumed in this 60 seconds:

> Sets the Session Expiry Interval. This value, measured in seconds, defines the maximum time that the broker will maintain the session for once the client disconnects...

```
16-06-2023 07:38:09.865 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00010000  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.865 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00111000  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.865 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00000000  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.865 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00000100  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.865 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 01001101  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.865 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 01010001  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.866 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(null): IN << CONNECT protocol=(MQTT, 5), hasPassword=true, isCleanStart=false, keepAliveTimeSeconds=60, clientIdentifier=sendMachineDataToS3Dev, hasUserNAme=true, isWillFlag=false, sessionExpiryInterval=10, receiveMAximum=65535  
16-06-2023 07:38:09:867 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@56b3fac)] TRACE  o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(sendMachineDataToS3Dev): OUT >> CONNACK connectReasonCode=0x00, sessionPresent=false, topicAliasMAximum=65535, maximumPacketSize=268435455  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.869 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(sendMachineDataToS3Dev): IN << SUBSCRIBE(1)  
    topic: topic/topic1, qos: AT_LEAST_ONCE, nolocal: false, retainHandling: SEND_AS_SUBSCRIBE, isRetainAsPublished: false  
16-06-2023 07:38:09.869 [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@56b3fac)] TRACE  o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - OUT >> SUBPACK(1)  
    1
16-06-2023 07:38:10.333 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] DEBUG o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.scanSessions Inspecting session: MQTTSessionState[session=MQTTSession[coreSessionId: bdd511bf-0c18-11ee-a591-c8940280cbb9], clientId='sendMAchineDataToS3Dev', subscriptions={topic/topic1=Pair[a=MqttTopicSubscription[qos=AT_LEAST_ONCE, noLocal=false, retainAsPublished=false, retainHandling=SEND_AS_SUBSCRIBE]], b = null]}, messageRefStore={}, addressMessageMap={topic.topic1={}}, pubRec=[], attached=true, outboundStore=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTSessionState$OutboundStore@661fe595, disconnectedTime=0, sessionExpiryInterval=10, isWill=false, willMessage=null, willTopic='null', willQosLevel=0, willDelayInterval=0, failed=false, maxPacketSize=0]          
16-06-2023 07:38:10.993 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(sendMachineDataToS3Dev): IN << DISCONNECT reasonCode=0x00  
.  
.  
.  
16-06-2023 07:38:16.997 [http-nio-11080-exec-7] INFO o.a.c.i.engine.AbstractCamelContext.log - Stopped send-machine-data-to-dev (paho-mqtt5://topic/topic1)
16-06-2023 07:38:16.442 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] DEBUG o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.scanSessions Inspecting session: MQTTSessionState[session=MQTTSession[coreSessionId: bdd511bf-0c18-11ee-a591-c8940280cbb9], clientId='sendMAchineDataToS3Dev', subscriptions={topic/topic1=Pair[a=MqttTopicSubscription[qos=AT_LEAST_ONCE, noLocal=false, retainAsPublished=false, retainHandling=SEND_AS_SUBSCRIBE]], b = null]}, messageRefStore={}, addressMessageMap={topic.topic1={}}, pubRec=[], attached=true, outboundStore=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTSessionState$OutboundStore@661fe595, disconnectedTime=1686901095994, sessionExpiryInterval=10, isWill=false, willMessage=null, willTopic='null', willQosLevel=0, willDelayInterval=0, failed=true, maxPacketSize=0]    
.  
.  
16-06-2023 07:38:26.129 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] DEBUG o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.scanSessions Inspecting session: MQTTSessionState[session=MQTTSession[coreSessionId: bdd511bf-0c18-11ee-a591-c8940280cbb9], clientId='sendMAchineDataToS3Dev', subscriptions={topic/topic1=Pair[a=MqttTopicSubscription[qos=AT_LEAST_ONCE, noLocal=false, retainAsPublished=false, retainHandling=SEND_AS_SUBSCRIBE]], b = null]}, messageRefStore={}, addressMessageMap={topic.topic1={}}, pubRec=[], attached=true, outboundStore=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTSessionState$OutboundStore@661fe595, disconnectedTime=0, sessionExpiryInterval=10, isWill=false, willMessage=null, willTopic='null', willQosLevel=0, willDelayInterval=0, failed=false, maxPacketSize=0]  
16-06-2023 07:38:26.130 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] DEBUG o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.scanSessions - Removing state for session: sendMachineDataToS3Dev  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.104 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00010000  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.105 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00100010  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.105 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00000000  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.105 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 00000100  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.105 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 01001101  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.105 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.c.p.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManager.readByte - 01010001  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.105 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] DEBUG o.a.a.a.c.protocol.mqtt.MQTTSession.<init> - MQTT sessionCreated: 8ba30c93-d068-4e07-ab29-e3e0144e1078  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.106 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(null): IN << CONNECT protocol=(MQTT, 5), hasPassword=true, isCleanStart=false, keepAliveTimeSeconds=60, clientIdentifier=ANK, hasUserNAme=true, isWillFlag=false, sessionExpiryInterval=10, receiveMAximum=65535  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.107 [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@56b3fac)] TRACE  o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(ANK): OUT >> CONNACK connectReasonCode=0x00, sessionPresent=false, topicAliasMAximum=65535, maximumPacketSize=268435455  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.119 [Thread-6 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage -MQTT(ANK): IN << PUBLISH(1) topic=topic/topic1, qos=1, retain=false, dup=false, remainingLength=1926, payload={  
    "content-spec":"sdf-data-message#v2",  
    "device": {  
        "deviceId":"c03"  
        }  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.120 [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@56b3fac)] TRACE  o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(ANK): OUT >> PUBACK(1)  
16-06-2023 07:38:35.123 [Thread-7 (activemq-netty-threads)] TRACE o.a.a.a.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTUtil.logMessage - MQTT(ANK): IN << DISCONNECT reasonCode=0x00
```

Comment: @JustinBertram, a mqtt client publish 100 messages to a topic, "topics/topic1". The aws-s3 client subscribes to that topic, but disconnects because an outage internet. I use the hawtio console and there I see the that those 100 messages are kept in the queue. If I reconnect the client aws-s3, it consumes the messages, even if the time specified in sessionexpiryinterval was elapsed, because they are still there..Why they not have been deleted at the end of the 60 seconds?

Comment: Even 10-15 minutes

Comment: For artemis - 2.27.0 and for apache camel - 3.20.5

Comment: Can you activate [debug logging for MQTT](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.27.1/mqtt.html#debug-logging), reproduce the problem, and then paste the log (or a link to the log) here?

Comment: Please add the log(s) to the original question.

Comment: I did another test without using the paho-mqtt5 component. I used a simple mqtt5 client as a subscriber and this client connects, subscribes, and then dissconects. I sended messages with a publisher and after that I recconnected the subscriber, after a period of Time greater than the sessionExpiryInterval. The meesages from the queue aren't consummed în this case, but they aren't deleted either.

Comment: When I used the paho-mqtt5, in order to simulate the issue of internet connection, I stopped the route that sends messages to aws s3. After the sessionexpiryinterval were elapsed I started the route again and the messages were consumed because în this case, the doStart method used by the paho-mqtt5 does the subscribe too, not just a connect

Comment: In the log file I see clearly that the session associated with the subscriber client expires, but why the messages arent deleted? Or expired?